# Visibility hidden is not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I want to hide a [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) tag using the *style* property:

```
<div style='visibility:hidden'>Sample</div>
```

But, the property is working for Firefox, but not Safari. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can use `<div style="display: none">Sample</div>`, that will remove the element completely.

Comment: i want to preserve the space for that element display:none will remove the element including space

Comment: works for me in safari 5.1.7 on win7 x64  http://jsfiddle.net/F5XNx/1/

Comment: Your missing ; at the end of CSS.

Comment: Out of curiosity does it work if the CSS rule is terminated by a semi-colon? I realise that, for the last CSS rule, the semi-colon is optional but I can't see why this CSS wouldn't work as-is.

Comment: Semicolon should not make a difference in this case. I have had a problem with inline styles in Android earlier, could you try to declare the style in a stylesheet instead? `... class="hidden" ...`, `.hidden {visibility: hidden;}`. This should not make a difference either, but for some reason it worked while debugging css in another project. According to http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/articles/standardcssproperties.html visibility is supported.

Comment: I definitely can't imagine that such an essential functionality like _visibility:hidden_ is not correctly implemented in Safari. There would be a lot of other persons on the internet complaining about this fact. Maybe you could give us more detailed information on your code and OS/Browser version so other people can try this.

Comment: What version of the browsers?

Answer (score 5):

A different approach could be:

```
<span style="opacity: 0">Sample</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `display: none;`:

The code would look like this:

```
<div style='display:none;'>Sample</div>
```

Comment: this don't preserve space (width-height). I'm using it to hide an iframe while loading, and this solution will break its init, as its not expecting 0x0

Comment: You can also use opacity: 0;