# Visibility Hidden Safari Bug

Tags: css, browser, safari, cross-browser, visibility

I would like to use `visibility` along with `translate` to control which content to show to the user.

As the user tabs through the navigation, therefore, the content below is transitioned via `translateX()` to show the proper information. Then, the containers in the viewport are shown to the user using `visibility: visible` and the containers outside of the viewport are hidden using `visibility: hidden`.

The CSS content for both containers looks something like:

```css
.visible {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This works as expected in Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason in Safari these properties don't perform as expected and the browser scrolls horizontally. [You can see this behavior yourself by testing using this link](https://nickbewley.com/?u=stackoverflow) (scroll below the fold and toggle between the tabs to observe the behavior).

I did see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321898/visibility-hidden-is-not-working-in-safari), but the solution does not seem to work for me in this instance. I would like to keep the structure of the site as is and am hoping that a workaround could solve for this Safari bug.

Comment: nice page :D ...

Comment: It seems to work fine on my end. Which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Raised as WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=262985

Comment: Have you tried using vendor prefix `-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);` & `-webkit-transform: translateX(-100vw);`  for browser compatibility?

Comment: @EreMännistö the issue is apparent on Safari 16.5.2 for example. None of the provided answers work.